# Stored Oracle Images Not Open

Tags: asp.net, forms, oracle, image

I have 30000 images stored in oracle 10g by oracle 6i  database and it open well using oracle forms&reports 6i but when trying open them in asp.net it is not opening and even when using toad popup editor it shows gray image using all formats.
I really have to show images using asp.net because it is very critical.
Thank all

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Please read [ask].  Nobody here has a clue what you are asking without providing concrete details on errors, sample code, etc.

Comment: You have an Oracle Forms 6i application that stores images in a database.  What format are the images in (i.e. are they gif's or jpeg's or tiff's or something else)?  What is the data type of the column they are stored in?

Comment: Thank you for responding...Format is .jpg which scanned directly to oracle forms and data type is blob.Note that images stored not by scanning is opening well in asp but scanned is not opening out of oracle forms.

Comment: Note That Mr.Justin images text start with MM and contain words such"Oracle Multimedia Tool"